# Function Split Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys basically I have an array here:

```
var someName = ["Rodel Merlien", "rodel.men"];
```

I declared a function named `spitName` which has a parameter name.

```
function spitName (name){

}
```

Breakdown of what I need:

1. `spitName` should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. For example "Rodel Merlien" should be returned as ["Rodel", "Merlien"]
2. Declare a new variable named `myInfo` and assign it to an empty object literal.
3. I need to add the following three key-value pairs to `myInfo`:
   Key: fullName
   Value: The result of calling spitName on the name string within someName.
   Key: skype
   Value: The Skype handle within someName.
   Key: github
   Value: github handle, enter link as a string. If not, set this to null instead.

How can I manage this?

Comment: Please add the desired input as you expect it. What should be the final output of the array you posted?

Comment: (a) Can you include a sample of the desired output? (b) Are you asking about how to split a name or how to create an object?

Comment: Breakdown:

1. spitName function should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. For example "Rodel Merlien" should be returned as ["Rodel", "Merlien"]

2. Declare a new variable named myInfo and assign it to an empty object literal.

3.  Add the following three key-value pairs to myInfo: 

Key: fullName Value: 
The result of calling spitName on the name string within someName. 
Key: skype Value: The Skype handle within someName. 

Key: github Value: github handle, enter link as a string. If not, set this to null instead.

Comment: @GaaraItachiUchiha Post the final output (**AS AN OBJECT** not **AS AN ARTICLE IN ENGLISH**).

Comment: -1 I'm not understand what you're asking in your 3rd objective. If you have multiple names, you can't assign them all to myInfo.

Answer (score 0):

For your split name problem, you can split a string using `String.split()`. Since you want to split by that whitespace or period, do:

```
function splitName(name) {
   return name.split(/[ .]+/);
}
```

This function takes in the string as `name` and splits it by either a whitespace or period.